# Why doesn't this little shell script work?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
initial=0.00
step=0.005 
num=10
mystrain=(2.475 0 0 1 0 0)
for((i=0;i<=num;i++))
do
    eval $(awk -v arr1="${mystrain[*]}" -v i=$i -v s=$step -v ini=$initial'
     BEGIN {split(arr1, adds, " ");
          for(j=1;j<=6;j++){
          adds[j]=ini+adds[j]*i*s;}
          printf("Setstrain=( %9.6f %9.6f %9.6f %9.6f %9.6f %9.6f    );",adds[1],adds[2],adds[3],adds[4],adds[5],adds[6])}' )
done
```

It will output the same as awk -help,I thought there might be a problem with the input to mystrain, but I wasn't able to find the correct input.

Comment: Your code says `awk ... -v ini=$initial' ...` but that single quote should not be part of the `ini=` variable.  You need a space between the variable declaration and the code.

Comment: `arr1` in awk is initially not an array. `-v` defines scalar variables. Later you use it as array, but it won't have the elements of the bash array `mystrain`.

Answer (score 0):

```
initial=0.00
step=0.005 
num=10
mystrain=(2.475 0 0 1 0 0)

awk -v arr1="${mystrain[*]}" \
    -v num="$num" \
    -v s="$step" \
    -v ini="$initial" '
    BEGIN {
       n=split(arr1, adds, " ")
       for (i=0; i<=num; i++){
            printf "Setstrain=(" 
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
              printf "%9.6f ", ini+adds[j]*i*s 
            }
            printf ")\n"
       }
}'


Setstrain=( 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.012375  0.000000  0.000000  0.005000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.024750  0.000000  0.000000  0.010000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.037125  0.000000  0.000000  0.015000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.049500  0.000000  0.000000  0.020000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.061875  0.000000  0.000000  0.025000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.074250  0.000000  0.000000  0.030000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.086625  0.000000  0.000000  0.035000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.099000  0.000000  0.000000  0.040000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.111375  0.000000  0.000000  0.045000  0.000000  0.000000 )
Setstrain=( 0.123750  0.000000  0.000000  0.050000  0.000000  0.000000 )
```